# Ionic with vuex gives compile error ( Property '$store' does not exist on type )

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, vuex, vuejs3

I wanted to try using vuex on a Ionic project so i just created a new project using the cli and added vuex and a simple store. I'm using typesccript and i get a compile error when im trying to use `this.$store` in my component. I've added a definition-file for the store:

```
// vuex.d.ts
import { ComponentCustomProperties } from 'vue'
import { Store } from 'vuex'

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  // declare your own store states
  interface State {
    count: number;
  }

  // provide typings for `this.$store`
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $store: Store<State>;
  }
}
```

and vs-code seems to be reading it because it provides intellisense or it. And the chrome consoles loggs what it should from what i can se. But it doesn't look like the compiler reads the definition file because it shows the error below in the browser.

> Failed to compile.
>
> src/views/Tab1.vue:28:22
> TS2339: Property '$store' does not exist on type '{ name: string; components: { ExploreContainer: { name: >string; props: { name: StringConstructor; }; }; IonHeader: DefineComponent<IonHeader & InputProps, >object, ... 9 more ..., {}>; IonToolbar: DefineComponent<...>; IonTitle: DefineComponent<...>; >IonContent: DefineComponent<...>; IonPage: DefineComponent<...>; };...'.
> 26 |   components: { ExploreContainer, IonHeader, IonToolbar, IonTitle, IonContent, IonPage },
> 27 |   mounted() {
>
> > 28 |     console.log(this.$store);
> > |                      ^^^^^^
> > 29 |   }
> > 30 | }
> > 31 |

You can explore the code in this repo: https://github.com/kebarvid/notifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the answer myself.

I didn't wrap my component in the `defineComponent` function, if i change the script part in Tab1.bue from

```
<script lang="ts">
import { IonPage, IonHeader, IonToolbar, IonTitle, IonContent } from '@ionic/vue';
import ExploreContainer from '@/components/ExploreContainer.vue';

export default {
  name: 'Tab1',
  components: { ExploreContainer, IonHeader, IonToolbar, IonTitle, IonContent, IonPage },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$store);
  }
}
</script>
```

to the following

```
<script lang="ts">
import { IonPage, IonHeader, IonToolbar, IonTitle, IonContent } from '@ionic/vue';
import ExploreContainer from '@/components/ExploreContainer.vue';
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent( {
  name: 'Tab1',
  components: { ExploreContainer, IonHeader, IonToolbar, IonTitle, IonContent, IonPage },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$store);
  }
})
</script>
```

I don't get the compile error. A little strange that this isn't done by default when you create a new app with the CLI since ionic wants you to use TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work for you, you need to name the vuex declaration file `shims-vuex.d.ts` and inside it import your store instance :

```
import { ComponentCustomProperties } from 'vue'

import store from '@/store'

  interface State {
    count: number;
  }

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
 
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $store: store;
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried that before (and tried it again now). Unfortunately it doesn't  make any difference. The compiler is still not recognizing there is a $store property on "this".

Comment: try to remove `import { ComponentCustomProperties } from 'vue'`

Comment: ^ No difference. Try it yourself by cloning the repo and see if anything works for you.